# Font-size is being set to a % of the screen automatically

Tags: html, css

I'm working on the responsive aspect of a website.
I have two boxes contained in a flex wrapper that I'd like to change from `flex-direction: row` to `flex-direction: column` when the display gets smaller.

I want them to go from

O O

to

O

O.

Although when I do this the font-size of ALL the children of the two boxes bugs.

Even when I set their font to `font-size: 2rem !important` the font still disobeys and is set to a % of the width of the screen.

See more with following pictures.

[Default look of website](https://i.stack.imgur.com/BdYck.png)

[Look of the wesbite with the media queries](https://i.stack.imgur.com/bo2QH.png)

Here we can see the "Lorem ipsum" header is way too big and does not correspond to 2 x 16px (2rem). It's size varies depending on the width of the screen and last time I checked it was 62.37626px or something.

The description text is also way too big when I haven't specified its new height in the media query. 
The two other text elements seem untouched though.

This is the default html up to the h2 which is bugging

```
section.box-container
  .lastest-projects
    h2 Lorem ipsum
```

This is the default css up to the h2 which is bugging

```
section.box-container
  display: flex
  margin: 0px 2rem

  .lastest-projects
    padding-right: 2em
    padding-top: 2em
    margin-right: 1rem
    border-right: 1px solid rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.1)
    width: 50%
    padding-bottom: 2em

    h2
      margin-bottom: 1rem
```

And these are the only media queries

```
@media only screen and (min-width: 600px)

  section.box-container
    flex-direction: column

  .lastest-projects
    width: auto
```

and

```
@media only screen and (min-width:600px)
  h2
    font-size: 2rem
```

If anyone knows why that is so, thanks in advance.

Comment: do you mind using a snippet to showcase the problem?